# Calling an action in another action in Redux React

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am learning Redux in React. I am using redux-thunk. I have an action like below

```
export const login = (value, history) => dispatch => {
    Axios.post('/api/users/login', value)
        .then(response => {
            dispatch(getAddress()); // I am calling like this
        })
        .catch(error => {});
}
```

My address action is like below

```
export const getAddress = () => dispatch => {
    Axios.get('/api/address')
        .then(response => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'getAddresses',
                payload: response.data
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {});
}
```

I am trying to display value in my component like below

```
    render() {
        return (
           <div>Hello {console.log(this.props)}</div> // I am getting empty object
        );
    }


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  addresses: state.address
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard);
```

But I am getting empty Object.

**I would like to redirect user to dashboard after login where the addresses will display. How can I do that ?**

Comment: I'm not sure if broken promise chains cause problems here, since there's only 2 actions and you don't use results from first action in second one, I'd expect both of them to be dispatched. The problem could be that responses don't meet your expectations, or there were errors that were suppressed with `catch`. Any way, it's a good practice to keep promise chains.

Comment: Do you have a reducer that process API response and store it as state?

Answer (score 4):

Redux thunk middleware allows to chain via `dispatch`, `dispatch(...)` returns dispatched action, i.e. a promise if promise chains weren't broken:

```
export const login = (value, history) => dispatch => {
    return Axios.post('/api/users/login', value) // return!
    .then(response => {
        return dispatch(getAddress()); // return!
    })
    .catch(error => {});
}

export const getAddress = () => dispatch => {
    return Axios.get('/api/address') // return!
    .then(response => {
        return dispatch({ // return!
            type: 'getAddresses',
            payload: response.data
        });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {});
}
```

Initial action should be dispatched somewhere. In vanilla Redux setup, it could be dispatched after store definition:

```
store.dispatch(login());
```

In React Redux setup, components are integral parts of Redux data flow. Asynchronous thunk is a side effect and it should be dispatched once in `componentDidMount`. In case of initial action, it should be dispatched in parent component:

```
@connect()
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    return this.props.dispatch(login());
  }

  render() {
    return !this.props.addresses ? 'Loading' :  <Dashboard />
  }
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qtphhp).

Comment: Thanks @estus for your reply. But your solution is not working. I saw your demo. You used `componentDidMount() {
    return this.props.dispatch(login());
  }`

I would not like to do that. I would like to redirect user to dashboard after login where the addresses will display. How can I do that ?

Comment: *I would not like to do that* - that's the problem then. Of course, you need to do that. I'm not aware of your components, but this can be done in a component that is a parent to dashboard.

Comment: Thanks @estus. Could you please say how can I get `address` data in my `dashboard` component using your solution? I would like to redirect user to dashboard after login where the addresses will display.

Comment: You can get it the way you originally did this and this was shown in the demo. You get it from a store with mapStateToProps.

Answer (score 2):

So this needs a very basic introduction to the flow of Redux with 'side effects'.

### The Redux Flow

1. [View]Your view reacts in various ways.
2. [Actions]We create an abstraction over these reactions called 'actions'.
3. [Dispatcher] This actions are dispatched to the store.
4. [Reducer] In the store we have logic written in 'reducers' that look at the actions and do manipulations to the store to update the store state.
5. [State]This state is loaded on the react state tree.

> Definition alert! In Redux stuff like calls to APIs are called side
>   effects. This is because you are doing something outside the typical
>   unidirectional data flow.

[image]

Hope you have understood this flow. I'm specifically concerned about a specific part that you seem to be confused about.
So in your code you have tried to do this.

```
 then(response => {
     return dispatch(getAddress()); 
 })
```

What your code is trying to do here is that, it's trying to 'dispatch' a side effect. This is wrong!

Dispatch is almost always a plain old JS object which is serializable. Typically you will have stereotypical structure like this. Which you seem to have in your other get address call.

```
{ 
    type: 'GET_ADDRESS_REQUEST_SUCCESS', 
    payload: {} 
}
```

So the proper way to approach your task is like this. Think of dispatching actions like emitting signals when various things happen.

```
export const login = (value, history) => dispatch => {
    Axios.post('/api/users/login', value)
        .then(response => {
            //Send out a success signal
            dispatch({
                type: 'loginSuccess',
                payload: response.data
            });

            //Now that I have logged in successfully I can call for my address
            //This is simply how you call an action within an action!
            getAddress();
        }).catch(error => {
            //login failed signal
            dispatch({
                type: 'loginFailed',
                payload: response
            }); // I am calling like this
        });
}

export const getAddress = () => dispatch => {
    Axios.get('/api/address')
        .then(response => {
            //Get address success signal
            dispatch({
                type: 'getAddressSuccess',
                payload: response.data
            });
        }).catch(function (error) {
            //Get addresses failed signal
            dispatch({
                type: 'getAddressFailed',
                payload: error
            }); 
        });
}
```

The next important part is the reducer, which you have not included here! If actions emits signals think of the reducers as a receiver which receives and processes this signal.
A reducer will update the existing state based on the action deployed.

```
export default function appReducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'getAddressSuccess': //Waiting on the signal!
            return Object.assign({},state,{address : action.payload} 
            //Set the proper address based on your payload from the api call

        default:
            return state

    }
}
```

You also should have setup your redux thunk configuration properly for this to fully work.
Cheers!

**============EDIT=============**

So upon checking the codebase, you have used the combine reducer to meld multiple reducers together.

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import authReducer from './authReducer';
import addressReducer from './addressReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  authReducer,
  addressReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

So in mapsStateToProps your store state will look like this

```
{
  authReducer: {
    // state managed by the authReducer 
  },
  addressReducer: {
    address: 'Test Streat, London'
  }
}
```

So change your mapStateToProps to look like this

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  addresses: state.addressReducer.address
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard);
```

Comment: Thanks @jdc for your long and descriptive reply. But your solution is not working. I would like to redirect user to dashboard after login where the addresses will display. How can I do that ?

Comment: Which part isn't working? Also are you using react router?

Comment: Thanks @jdc. I am not using react router. I am using `history.push('/dashboard');`. How can I display data/get data in my component ? 

I am getting this output https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlCeR.png   if I am using below code in my component.

`render() {
  return (
      <div>Hello {console.log(this.props)}</div>
    );
 }`

Comment: I don't think this is part of the initial question you asked which was just how to call an action with in an action. I am guessing you haven't set up your redux integrations properly. You should first follow a tutorial on how to integrate react and redux.

Comment: Thank you @jdc91.  This later part of  initial question. I have to call an action within an action and display that data in a Component. My setup of redux is working as I found.

Comment: Thanks @jdc91. Could you please say how can I get `address` data in my `dashboard` component using your solution? I would like to redirect user to dashboard after login where the addresses will display.

Comment: Here is `addressReducer` code

`const initialState = {
    address: {}
};

const addressReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'getAddresses': {
            return {
                address: action.payload
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default addressReducer;`

Comment: How did you deduce that your redux set up is correct? Will need to look at the total codebase to figure this out.

Comment: Thanks @jdc91. Here is the total codebase.  https://github.com/afoysal/mern

Comment: I have updated with the fix! This should be the problem. @abuabu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190734/discussion-between-jdc91-and-abu-abu).